# How do I change the permissions in openshift container platform?

Tags: linux, docker, openshift

I am new to Openshift. 
I have deployed an application in openshift. When I checked the logs, there is permission denied error for some files.
Now, I want to change the permissions on the the container that is already deployed in Openshift, but I am getting, "Operation not permitted" warning. How do I fix this ?

This is for linux running latest version of MongoDB. I have already tried executing RUN chmod 777 /path/to/directory in my docker file, created the image and pulled the same image in my yaml file, which I am deploying in my openshift. However, when I check my docker container, it shows that the permissions are changed for that directory, but when I deploy, I get the warning in my logs as "permission denied".

```
FROM node:10.16.3

RUN apt update && apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin

# Set the workdir /var/www/myapp
WORKDIR /var/www/myapp

# Copy the package.json to workdir
COPY package.json .

# Run npm install - install the npm dependencies
RUN npm install

RUN npm install sqlite3

# Copy application source
COPY . .

RUN chown -R admin:admin /var/www/myapp

RUN chmod 775 /var/www/myapp

USER admin

# Copy .env.docker to workdir/.env - use the docker env
#COPY .env.docker ./.env

# Expose application ports - (4300 - for API and 4301 - for front end)
# EXPOSE 4300 4301
EXPOSE 52000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Athough, when I run my dockerifle, the permissions have changed, but when I try to deploy in my openshift, I get permission denied for some files in that directory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default any container started in OpenShift gets a random user ID. Therefor images not designed to handle such a random UID will fail with permission errors.

In order to get your image working I recommed you read following Article of the latest OpenShift documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/openshift_images/create-images.html

Here the short version that relates to your issue:

> SUPPORT ARBITRARY USER IDS
>
> By default, OpenShift Container Platform
> runs containers using an arbitrarily assigned user ID. This provides
> additional security against processes escaping the container due to a
> container engine vulnerability and thereby achieving escalated
> permissions on the host node.
>
> For an image to support running as an arbitrary user, directories and
> files that may be written to by processes in the image should be owned
> by the root group and be read/writable by that group. Files to be
> executed should also have group execute permissions.
>
> Adding the following to your Dockerfile sets the directory and file
> permissions to allow users in the root group to access them in the
> built image:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /some/directory && \
    chmod -R g=u /some/directory
```

> Because the container user is always a member of the root group, the container user can read and write
> these files. The root group does not have any special permissions
> (unlike the root user) so there are no security concerns with this
> arrangement. In addition, the processes running in the container must
> not listen on privileged ports (ports below 1024), since they are not
> running as a privileged user.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to my `Dockerfile` worked:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /some/directory && \
    chmod -R g=u /some/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The following changes in the Dockerfile solved the issue for me

```
#Add user 
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/ubuntu -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 ubuntu
#Add permissions
RUN chown -R ubuntu:root /home/ubuntu && \
    chgrp -R 0 /home/ubuntu && \
    chmod -R 775 /home/ubuntu 
##Specify the user with UID
USER 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift runs the Pod with arbitrary UID by default. You can check what UID is used by in the pod using `oc rsh <pod name> id`. Your pod might run not using `admin` you specified.

The container you built is required `admin` permission, so you should configure `anyuid` SCC to the default serviceaccount for avoid the permission error.
Further information about SCC is here: [Enable Container Images that Require Root](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-dockerhub-images-that-require-root)
.

e.g.> `default` scc is using to run pod by default

```
$ oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
$ oc delete pod <your pod name>
```

FYI, before building your image, checking here:[General Container Image Guidelines](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines)
 is helpful to build your image used on OpenShift.