# Permission denied error while running influx arm64 docker image as a container

Tags: docker, influxdb, arm64

I'm running influx arm64 **arm64v8/influxdb** docker image as a container but facing following permission denied issue.
Can some one please help with this issue? Thank you in advance.

```
admin@ynm583:~/***/***/***fa$ docker logs 0b3
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/influxdb2/engine': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

I have clashed with this problem when trying to run influxdb in OpenShift.
The problem was in OpenShift work: it runs containers as a non-root user. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438601/permission-denied-error-while-running-influx-arm64-docker-image-as-a-container) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473832/how-do-i-change-the-permissions-in-openshift-container-platform)

Comment: Hi! I'm also stuck with this, could you please elaborate a bit more what the solution should be? Where should that `RUN chgrp -R 0 /some/directory && chmod -R g=u /some/directory` go in the Dockerfile? Thanks

Comment: @SaverioGuzzo at the end of Dockerfile. May be instead of cmd/entrypoint. For example, full Dockerfile:

FROM influxdb:1.8

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/lib/influxdb/ && chgrp -R 0 /var/lib/influxdb && chmod -R g=u /var/lib/influxdb

Comment: Or you can connect read-write volume to pod

Answer (score 0):

This might be a user-privilege issue: Make sure user `admin` is allowed to execute `docker` commands. This can be done via the command `sudo usermod -a -G docker $(whoami)` (you might need restart your terminal session/system for this to take effect).

Alternatively, you could run your `docker`(`-compose`) commands with `sudo` (this is discouraged though).

Answer (score 0):

[student@workstation ~]$ oc logs docker-nginx
...output omitted...
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/12/02 18:51:45 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2022/12/02 18:51:45 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)
The pod failed to start because of permission issues for the nginx directories.

Create a debug pod for the docker-nginx pod.

[student@workstation ~]$ oc debug pod/docker-nginx
Starting pod/docker-nginx-debug ...
Pod IP: 10.8.0.72
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

$
From the debug pod, verify the permissions of the /etc/nginx and /var/cache/nginx directories.

$ ls -la /etc/ | grep nginx
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     132 Nov 15 13:14 nginx
$ ls -la /var/cache | grep nginx
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   6 Oct 19 09:32 nginx