# Same Yaml working in kubernetes but giving error in Openshift (ROSA)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have the below yaml which is running fine in kubernetes but not working in Openshift with below error. Many more components yaml run seamlessly and this log path is created but only for this one it is not working.

Error:

```
Warning  FailedPostStartHook  12m (x2 over 12m)  kubelet            Exec lifecycle hook ([/bin/sh -c echo "`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N'` [main] [] INFO  [postStarthook] - Starting txe ..."
>>/var/seamless/log/txe/txe.log]) for Container "ers-txe" in Pod "ers-txe-547b59778f-2zpgm_ers(36a9bfc2-5817-4ed4-bbee-9923580d9fba)" failed - error: command '/bin/sh -c echo "`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N'` [main] [] INFO  [postStarthook] - Starting txe ..."
>>/var/seamless/log/txe/txe.log' exited with 1: /bin/sh: can't create /var/seamless/log/txe/txe.log: Permission denied , message: "/bin/sh: can't create /var/seamless/log/txe/txe.log: Permission denied\n"   Normal   Killing            12m (x2 over 12m)  kubelet  FailedPostStartHook
```

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to paste complete yaml so let me know what other information is required. My yaml contains
PV - for txe component
PVC - for txe component
PV - for mysql
PVC - for mysql
ClusterIP service
Deployment file

Comment: Including any source code at all would be helpful; the Deployment spec seems like the really important thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the permissions in openshift container platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473832/how-do-i-change-the-permissions-in-openshift-container-platform)

Comment: I was missing SecurityContext filed in container spec. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running as root by default in kube, and as the high UID in OpenShift.

This error line is where I think the issue is:
"/bin/sh: can't create /var/seamless/log/txe/txe.log: Permission denied\n"

Check file permissions on that directory, check UID/GID that you're running as.

In OpenShift, you usually leverage the GID (not the UID) of the container runtime processes, so I would suggest a small rebuild of your container image to add "chgrp group ... chmod g+w ..." on the directories in question.

The other quick hack to fix this is, remembering that all of these directories are transient anyway, just change your command to write to /tmp instead.

Comment: I was missing SecurityContext filed in container spec. Please see my answer. Never the less thankyou for answering it.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing below parameter in my YAML file. I added below in container's spec section and issue was resolved. This field was not required in my YAML when I run in kubernetes. By default many things are restricted in openshift.

```
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Comment: This is a somewhat problematic method by which you've "solved" the problem.

I strongly suspect you're not actually using the privileged functionality at all, but by requesting it you're forcing the pod to be admitted via a different SCC which also covers what it is that you need.

I would propose you change that to:

```
securityContent:
  runAsUser: 0
```

And see if the problem is still satisfied.  This will admit you via (assuming defaults) the "anyuid" SCC instead of "restricted".